# Splitting input string (delivery address data) based on length and commas

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need help please to split the source data in XML based on it's character length and factor in whether it's in the middle of a word and if it has any commas. EG: My delivery address lines can't be more than 35 characters in length(this includes any whitespace, commas etc, and ideally I'd like to split the address to ensure the 2 address lines that I'd like to output do not exceed 35 characters, and if I split the source data based on this maximum restriction that I'm either doing it at the point of a comma or either at the end of a word, to then append the remaining data to the next line and so on, as to not lose any of the data supplied by the customer(where avoidable).

I'm currently using **XSLT Version 1**, but can support using Version 2 if needed.

Here is my source data, what I've been trying to do and what my desired output is.  FYI my output is in a pipe-delimited format.

XML

```
<AddressData> 
   <Delivery> 
      <ConsigneeAddress>Rosedal 67, departamento 3A, Lomasde Chapultepec, Miguel hidalgo</ConsigneeAddress> 
      <ConsigneeAddress2/> 
   </Delivery> 
   <Delivery> 
      <ConsigneeAddress>Str.Codreanu,30, Chisinau, MD-200018,</ConsigneeAddress> 
      <ConsigneeAddress2>Moldova, Republic of</ConsigneeAddress2> 
   </Delivery> 
</AddressData>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="/AddressData/Delivery">
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(./ConsigneeAddress) &#62; 35">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(./ConsigneeAddress,',')"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(./ConsigneeAddress,','),',')"/>
                            <xsl:if test="./ConsigneeAddress2=''">
                                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(./ConsigneeAddress,','),','),./ConsigneeZipCode))"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="./ConsigneeAddress2!=''">
                                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./ConsigneeAddress2)"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(./ConsigneeAddress,','),','))"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./ConsigneeAddress"/>
                    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./ConsigneeAddress2"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

> Rosedal 67,  departamento 3A|Lomasde Chapultepec, Miguel hidalgo
>   Str.Codreanu,30, Chisinau,|MD-200018, Moldova, Republic of

Any assistance/help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the source XML and XSLT as code (that can be easily copy-and-pasted into a XML tool such as http://xsltransform.net/) rather than as images. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I can attempt to add the code again.  When I did this before making my post the formatting did not look correct, like other posts I had read it kept the formatting and the colours as per the editor used (eg XMLSpy), but I could not replicate this.  Here it is again:

Comment: Source:  `<AddressData>`
`<Delivery>`
`<ConsigneeAddress>Rosedal 67, departamento 3A, Lomasde Chapultepec, Miguel hidalgo</ConsigneeAddress>`
`<ConsigneeAddress2></ConsigneeAddress2>`
`</Delivery>`
`<Delivery>`
`<ConsigneeAddress>Str.Codreanu,30, Chisinau, MD-200018,</ConsigneeAddress>`
`<ConsigneeAddress2>Moldova, Republic of</ConsigneeAddress2>`
`</Delivery>`
`</AddressData>`

Comment: XSLT:  I've tried to add the XSLT but get an error about it exceeding the maximum number of characters, so I've uploaded the file to Google Drive and created a link for it instead:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ry3wqoFp1Vc1o4Q2ZQLVhYekE

Comment: I have added the XML and XSLT to the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you can change to **XSLT 2**, as tt has much more powerful features.
One of them, useful in your case is `analyze-string`.

You can use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/AddressData/Delivery">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ConsigneeAddress"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConsigneeAddress">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="."
      regex="(\w.{{0,33}}\w)(,\s*|$)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
          <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

A piece of explanation concerning the regex used:

Each substring to match:

- Should start with a word character (`\w`).
- Then it should contain up to 33 arbitrary characters.
  Note that "ordinary" regex would have **single** `{` and `}`
  but here (due to XSLT syntax) they must be doubled.
- The last char to capture is again a word character.

All the above items (total up to 35 chars) constitute the 1st capturing group.

After that there is another group containing 2 variants:

- either a comma and a sequence of "white" chars,
- or the end of the string.

They also should be "consumed" here in order to start the next search
after them.

From these 2 groups we are actually interested only in the first,
so in the XSLT script `value-of` statement prints out only this
first group (`regex-group(1)`).

After the captured group was printed out, the script prints out a `|`,
but only "in the middle ot the sequence" (i.e. not after the last
matched string).

The main template also prints a *newline* after each *ConsigneeAddress*
but the last.

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo, I appreciate all your help, and I can see this working, however when I try to incorporate this into my template, I am struggling to get it to work, I've supplied 2 hyperlinks to the XML and the template again (it has additional fields that I originally removed).  Line 36, where I have added a comment is where the 2 address lines need to go, I've been pulling my hair out over this for the past 2 hours.  Source XML:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ry3wqoFp1VVnVjZlE3R3dzMnM   Transform:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ry3wqoFp1VSnpJRjNCaC1pcmc  Thank you.

Comment: Apologies in advance, I know this is different to what I posted, but I removed data to make it look simpler, and by doing so I can't actually get your solution to now work in my template, next time I won't do this, and supply data as is.

Comment: I missed that in your example you uset *output* in *text* mode. Now I changed the mode and the whole solution too.

Comment: Hi, it's not just the output mode that is different, the contents of the 2 files (Source and Transform) that are different too.  Lastly, when it's splitting the address lines, it can't output them to more than 2 lines, that's also including if there is a value in <ConsigneeAddress2>.  If <ConsigneeAddress1> is more than 35, you'll then append the rest to line2 in the output and whatever is in <ConsigneeAddress2> is just added to the end of it, even if the total length of the output of line2 then exceeds 35 characters, that's fine, because the System will then just ignore the end characters.

Comment: Eventually, I'd like us to have the ability to accept 3 Lines of address, so the code will then be changed in the XSLT to output 3 lines of address, each separated by a pipe, with the same logic as above.

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo.  I found an issue with your regex (\w.{{0,33}}\w)(,\s*|$).  It does not recognise or use the full address if it starts with numbers, eg 58-206 AVENIDA TECNOLOGICO  QUERETARO, it will select the value of this input XML as 206 AVENIDA TECNOLOGICO  QUERETARO.  This is a big problem, as part of the delivery address is missing.  There will always be possibility of addresses that start with numbers.  Can you help please, thank you.

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo, the same Regex above also fails to find the input string 'Oybek 57-17 .'  I've put this in single quotes so that you can see the beginning and end, it ends with a space and full stop.  It ignores this address from the input XML altogether.